# write.csv() within a user defined function : R

Tags: r, csv

I have created a function wherein I want to export the generated data frame result in a .csv file. But every time I run the function, the data should be stored in a separate file as specified by the user function. Eg:

```
write<- function (a, b, y)  
{
  x <- a + b
  write.csv(x, file = paste0(",y,"), fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")
}
```

> write(2, 3, "C:\Users\lol\Desktop\file1.csv")
>
> write(2, 4, "C:\Users\lol\Desktop\file2.csv")

Is there any way by which this can be done?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of `paste0(",y,")` you should write `y`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `write.csv`-call you specify the `file` argument with `paste0(",y,")` which evaluates to `,y,` and not to the value of `y` of your `write` function.

You can substitute `paste0(",y,")` with `y` or you can do the follwoing, if the folder, where the files are stored is often the same:

```
write <- function (a, b, filename, folder = "C:/Users/lol/Desktop/") {
  x <- a + b
  write.csv(x, file = paste0(folder, filename), fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")
}

write(2, 3, "file1.csv")
```

By specifying the folder argument with `"C:/Users/lol/Desktop/"` this is set as the default value. If you then want to use a different folder you can simply do:

```
write(2, 3, "file1.csv", "C:/Users/rofl/Desktop/")
```